# How to change toolbar control color?

Tags: winapi

I use standard Toolbar class. I changed its Win7 theme to empty theme, it looks like plain greyed colored. How I can change its gray BG color to other? To e.g.  dark blue, or brown? I want to colorize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `TBSTYLE_CUSTOMERASE` style on the control:

> **TBSTYLE_CUSTOMERASE**
>
> Version 4.70. Generates NM_CUSTOMDRAW notification
>   codes when the toolbar processes WM_ERASEBKGND messages.

Then you handle the [`NM_CUSTOMDRAW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775528(v=vs.85).aspx) notification and when you get the `CDDS_PREERASE` event, draw your own background and return `CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT`.

Comment: 100Pts to Griffindor. Tks:)